# How can I stretch a single widget in a horizantal layout in PyQt4?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

Here all three pushbutton are equivalent in size, how to increase size of only first pushbutton so that it occupies more space than other two buttons.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class AllWidgets(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(AllWidgets, self).__init__()
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        #code for pushbutton 1
        pushbutton_1 = QtGui.QPushButton()
        pushbutton_1.setText('First')
        layout.addWidget(pushbutton_1)
        #code for pushbutton 2
        pushbutton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton()
        pushbutton_2.setText('Second')
        layout.addWidget(pushbutton_2)
        #code for pushbutton 3
        pushbutton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton()
        pushbutton_3.setText('Third')
        layout.addWidget(pushbutton_3)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    display = AllWidgets()
    display.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second (optional) argument of `addWigdet()` is the strech factor. If you want first button to stretch, simply do:

```
layout.addWidget(pushbutton_1, 1)
```

If you want all buttons to stretch, but the first one to be bigger, you simply need to use different stretch factors:

```
layout.addWidget(pushbutton_1, 2)
layout.addWidget(pushbutton_2, 1)
layout.addWidget(pushbutton_3, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this stretching is happening only after I maximize the window, can I do something such that at the first time it shows output when not maximized, first push button occupies more space?

Comment: You can try: `pushbutton_1.setMinimumWidth()` with the minimum width you want, in pixels. Or, if you prefer, you could also set the minimum width of the window, using `self.setMinimumWidth()`.